# change default wordpress query to orderby title

Tags: wordpress, function

I would like to change the wordpress default query to orderby title when viewing a category, rather than the post id.

For reasons too boring to explain(!) I would like to change the default setting rather than use a custom query (which I know how to do)

Ideally it would be some code that goes in the functions.php of my template, rather than having to hack the core installation.

Thanks for your help people!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your archive.php, find the code

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

and replace it with:

```
$cat_posts = new WP_Query($query_string."&orderby=title&order=ASC");
if ($cat_posts->have_posts()):while($cat_posts->have_posts()):$cat_posts->the_post();
```

this should do the trick.

update: this is taken if you want to change the source code.

Comment: That's great thanks -  and seems to work... in the end though I used a plugin called 'WP Post Sorting' which allows changing of defaults for each category independently, and seems to work very well

Answer (score 42):

You can also use [the action 'pre_get_posts'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to change the orderby and order variables like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_get_posts' );

function custom_get_posts( $query ) {

  if( (is_category() || is_archive()) && $query->is_main_query() ) {    
    $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'name';
    $query->query_vars['order'] = 'ASC';
  }

}
```

Note: the is_main_query() check helps make sure you don't cause unintended behaviors in plugins and theme functionality. Removing it is OK but make sure you know what else you are affecting!

Comment: +1 for working with the existing query, and coming up with something that goes in functions.php like the question states.

Comment: +1 This method will change the **default query**, so that `wp_reset_query()` won't reset the *order* back to default. And will hit the database only once.

Comment: Keep an eye on what you realy want to change by adding a filter. This filter applies on EVERY query WP makes, be it homepage posts list, menu items, category posts or else. So for example the solution above should also affect the order of menu items (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Added the $query->is_main_query() check which makes this much safer. You definitely want to know what you're doing with this method!

Comment: you should use the set-method instead of overwriting the query_vars directly.
    $query->set('orderby', 'name');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');

Answer (score 0):

well you can do 1 another thing in your archive.php

use this line of code

```
global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string."&orderby=title&order=ASC");
```

before this line of code

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

you will get what you desire by the default wordpress loop.
i hope this will help you much.

thank you all.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts
"This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose."