# Altering global post query (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if there is a way to alter the global wordpress posts query.

Let's say that I'm in a tags archive. I need to be able to change the order and posts_per_page variables

when I use this:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
```

It changes the variable, but the posts order is not changed.

Creating another query would do the job, but doing so would require me to use different queries for tags, archives, search results and etc, which is not an option for me.

I hope you understand what it is that I need.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use query_posts() and pass thru your arguments it will modify the loop. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: How did I miss that! Thank you!

Comment: There is a better way to do that using `pre_get_posts` filter here is the complete answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9687399/123618

Answer (score 3):

I modify wordpress query from functions.php:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','myf88');function myf88($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )   {
        if (  $query->is_category ) {
            $query->set('post_type', array('post','page','my_postType') );
            add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'MyFilterFunction_1' ); 
        }
        //for "PAGE" type, this doesnt work (IT is WORDPRESS FAULT) , so you may modify "query_posts" in page.php,before loop
    }
}
function MyFilterFunction_1($where) {global $wpdb;  $where .= " AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_name NOT LIKE 'Journal%')"; return $where;  }
```